# ColdFusion to PHP conversion: How to translate #gettable1["size#i#title"][gettable1.currentrow]#

Tags: php, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am currently converting an application from ColdFusion to PHP and I ran into a question about a section of the code. I have a table, let's call it "table1", that has this structure:

```
table1
-------------------

id 
... 
size36 
size36title 
size37 
size37title 
... 
size80 
size80title
```

Then I have an insert based on a POST in a CFM action which looks like this:

```
<cfquery name="gettable1" datasource="#application.datasource#">
select * from table1 where id = '#modelId#'
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="gettable1">

    insert into table1( name, rank  <cfloop from="38" to="80" index="i" step="2">, size#i#, size#i#title</cfloop>)
    values(
    '#gettable1.name#', 
    '#gettable1.rank#', 
    <cfloop from="38" to="80" index="i" step="2">, 
        '#gettable1["size#i#"][gettable1.currentrow]#', 
        '#gettable1["size#i#title"][gettable1.currentrow]#'
    </cfloop>)

</cfloop>
```

I do not understand what the syntax below does or what should I replace it with in my `foreach` loop in PHP.

> '#gettable1["size#i#"][gettable1.currentrow]#'

So far I did a `foreach` like this:

```
$gettable1 = \DB::table('table1')->where('id','=',getmodel->modelId);
foreach($gettable1 as $item){
    $ins = 'insert into table1( name, rank  ';
    for($i=38;$i<=80;$i=$i+2)
    {
        $ins=$ins.', size'.$i.', size'.$i.'title';
    }

    $ins=$ins.') values('.$item[0]->name.', '.$gettable1[0]->rank','; 
    for($i=38;$i<=80;$i=$i+2)
    {
        $ins=$ins.','...// here lies the problem
    }
    $ins=$ins.');';

}
```

Normally I would translate that using `$item`, but something tells me I should address it using `$gettable1[...][gettable1->currentrow]`? Can anyone help me understand how to solve this thing?

**EDIT**

Is this equivalent in the above code?

```
ColdFusion:  <cfloop....
             ...
             #gettable1["size#i#"][gettable1.currentrow]#

PHP/Laravel: $currentro = 0;
             foreach($gettable1 as $item)
             {
                ... 
                $gettable1["size'.$i.'"][$currentrow];
                $currentrrow++;
             }
```

**SOLUTION**

```
             foreach($gettable1 as $item)
             {
                ... 
                $item->{"size'.$i.'"};
             }
```

Comment: *I do not understand what this syntax does* I am not a PHP guy, but that syntax is just a way of saying, "use the value of some dynamic column name ie `size#i#` in the current row of the resultset. Having said that A) I would not bother translating the existing query. A simpler way to copy data from one table is to use a single query with an INSERT/SELECT, ie a `INSERT INTO Table (Columns) / SELECT Columns FROM Table WHERE ...`.  B) When you see column names like "size1,size2,size3, ...." it is usually a good sign the table should be normalized.

Comment: Thanks but I solved it, by ignoring [currentrow] and by using $item to refer to the named field. Thank you anyway. "sizexx" is the actual columnname, actually it is "size38", "size38Title", "size39","size39Title"... and so on, and I cannot change the logic of the application. I just need to replicate it.

Comment: An `insert into/select` does the same thing, only more efficiently. BTW, SO uses a Q&A (question and answer) format. You can go ahead and post your solution as an "answer" so it is more visible.  (Answering your own question is allowed on SO).